# Grails createCriteria returning null criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, nullpointerexception, grails-orm

I'm getting a strange NullPointerException in grails 2.1.1.

```
HibernateCriteriaBuilder crit = FattoriIndicatori.createCriteria()
crit.createAlias("indicatori","ind")... // NPE here, because underlying Criteria is null
```

- the class is listed in hibernate-cfg
- other classes from the same config file work just right
- the class not been added recently, it's there since a long time

Surely something is missing, but I can't see it.

Edit: I am sure that the class is correctly configured beacuse this code works:

```
HibernateCriteriaBuilder crit = FattoriIndicatori.createCriteria()
Number res = crit.get {
projections {
    count()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the class present inside `grails-app/domain`? `createCriteria()` is just another statically metaClass method added to `GrailsDomainClass` artefact type. If `FattoriIndicatori` is not a domain class artefact type then I do not think it will return a builder.

Comment: @dmahapatro The OP have the class definition in `hibernate-cfg`. All hibernate classes receive the GORM methods too.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Apologize. This happens when you we roam around domain classes and forget about boiler plate mechanism. :). Ric- I guess you also have registered the class in `<session-factory>`? You would get access to [dynamic methods only if you register in session-factory](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/hibernate.html).

Comment: dmahapatro: the class is both a @Entity and it's present in a "mapping class" element in the session factory configuration.
It does return a builder, but using that results in NPE because (I looked at it in debugger) the internal Criteria field is null.
The entity works perfectly if I use GORM dsl, and that's the way I took to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that certain methods on `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` only work when called from within the closure passed to `get`, `list`, etc.

```
HibernateCriteriaBuilder crit = FattoriIndicatori.createCriteria()
def results = crit.list {
  createAlias("indicatori","ind")
  eq('ind.something', 'value')
}
```

will work fine.  The `list` method does some initialization (including creating the underlying `Criteria` instance, which is initially `null`), then calls the closure to build up the criteria specification, then executes the resulting query and returns the results.

Comment: thanks, I have the confirmation it's not my fault; I think this is a bug, because I don't think that createAlias is some obscure and/or rarely used method... do you agree?

Comment: @RiccardoCossu no, it's not a bug, because this is how `HibernateCriteriaBuilder` is designed to be used - you call `list` or `get` and pass a closure that contains the criteria definition.  For reusable criteria specifications that don't belong to a particular query you should use [`DetachedCriteria`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria) instead.

Comment: Ok, this could be clearer in the docs; I think it's easy for a hibernate expert / GORM beginner like me to fall in this trap (the original code would work in plain Hibernate)

Comment: @RiccardoCossu https://github.com/grails/grails-doc is always happy to receive patches/pull-requests :-)

Comment: Sorry ... i followed documentation. I created an object as said and call a public method ... and it did not works. This is against common sense and seems clearly like a bug or design problem.